# Artifact dependency direction in deployment diagram

Tags: deployment, dependencies, uml

I have some troubles defining some dependencies for artifacts in a deployment diagram for the following cases:

- A service (MyService) launched by a process supervisor (Supervisord, init, a cron job, ...)
- Some HTML files served by a static HTTP file server

There is a kind of double dependency since a service (or HTML files) needs a process supervisor (or an HTTP file server); and obviously the process supervisor (or the HTTP file server) has a configuration pointing to the supervised process (or the files to serve).

I see the following modeling possibilities:

1. The process supervisor has a dependency to the service since it controls it
2. The service has a dependency to the process supervisor since it cannot run without it
3. Double dependency
4. We consider the process supervisor is a UML node, and the service runs in this node

[image]

For me, the most logical would be 1) since the process supervisor must have knowledge about the service to supervise. And if 4) seems to be a good answer, I feel I lose a way to explicitly ask for a deployment of a specific process supervisor artifact (Supervisord, or cron, or ...).

If we want to emphasize the needs of the two artifacts, is there a standard approach, or is the answer debatable?

Answer (score 1):

> A service (MyService) launched by a process supervisor (Supervisord, init, a cron job, ...)
>
> The service has a dependency to the process supervisor since it cannot run without it

Based on the first statement I don't think that the second one is true.

The Service doesn't communicate with the launcher (supervisor) in any way (how would you communicate with cron?) -- the supervisor just launches and observes the service; so I don't see a dependency. If a cron were to die, then the service would happily carry on (bar of cron killing its suprocesses).